# Getting long term search stats

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console

I want to monitor long-term stats for my site's Google search results (keywords, average positions).

- Google Analytics site shows results for the last 90 days only
- the same limitation for Google Webmasters Tools
- I've tried using GA API to retrieve this data so I could store it and use later; however, it only returns 2 keyword sets with 1 hit each, and hundreds in the group "keywords not provided". Quite strange, because GA and GWT sites show much more keyword sets with detailed data for the same period of time.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I have tried to change dates in URL as well, and they did not display old data. Look's like they store data for 90 days only. You have to download data yourself. Or Discover other premium analytic tools yourself :D

Answer (score 1):

There are some workarounds, which all make use of the same schema:

- tie search console with GA, with the goal to make mapping of search keywords to landing pages and their GA metrics possible
- download daily data from GA

The workarounds are:

- iMacros (used it personally),
- [script in Python](https://moz.com/ugc/how-to-get-the-data-you-need-from-googles-search-analytics-api) (there must be a bunch of such scripts),
- third part tools, like seomonitor or deep crawl, where you provide an access to both of GA and search console and tools make the rest for you.